# How to linearize the following constraint on abs terms with coefficients of mixed signs

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

I am implementing an optimization program on 2 variables with a constraint of the form:

2*|x1| + 3*|x2| <= 2.25 * (|x1| + |x2|)

Given that the effective coefficients on the two abs terms are + and -, I'm unsure if and how this constraint can be linearized. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: So you want $x_1+3x_2\ge0$ and $x_1-8x_2\ge0$ for $x_1\ge0$ and $x_1+3x_2\le0,x_1-8x_2\le0$ for $x_1\le0$. At the moment I cannot see how to linearize that. I guess you could solve separately for $x_1\ge0$ and $x_1\le0$.

Comment: I have simplified the problem here for discussion purposes. The problem is actually on 26000 variables. So, an approach like this would blow up in complexity. I am hoping there exists a cleaner and scalable way of doing this.

Comment: The problem is not convex, so no, you're stuck with a binary implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, this forms a non-convex feasible region, so there is no way to do this in a pure continuous LP (even though some other answers -- now deleted- - seem to indicate otherwise) unless there are other special properties of the model we can exploit. Note that any LP has a convex feasible region.

Your particular constraint can be rewritten as $|x_2|\le \frac{1}{3}|x_1|$, and the feasible region looks like:

[image]

We do not have to give up however. From the picture it is clear we can solve this in two parts: first with $x_1\ge 0$ and then with $x_1\le 0$ and pick the best solution of the two sub-models.

Another approach is to use just one model, but with binary variables. We can model this constraint with the aid of two binary variable $\delta_1,\delta_2 \in \{0,1\}$ as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
 &x_1 = x_1^{plus} - x_1^{min}\\
 &x_1^{plus} \le M \delta_1 \\ 
 &x_1^{min} \le M (1-\delta_1) \\ 
 &x_2 = x_2^{plus} - x_2^{min}\\
 &x_2^{plus} \le \frac{1}{3}M \delta_2 \\ 
 &x_2^{min} \le \frac{1}{3}M (1-\delta_2) \\
 &x_2^{plus}+x_2^{min} \le \frac{1}{3}(x_1^{plus}+x_1^{min})\\
 & x_1 \in [-M,M] \\ 
 & x_2 \in [-\frac{1}{3}M,\frac{1}{3}M] \\
 & x_1^{plus}, x_1^{min},x_2^{plus}, x_2^{min} \ge 0\\
 & \delta_1,\delta_2 \in \{0,1\} 
\end{align}
$$
Note that $M$,$\frac{1}{3}M$ form bounds on the $x_1$ and $x_2$ variables. Because of the binary variables you need a MIP solver to handle this.

A slightly more compact formulation uses just one binary variable:
$$
\begin{align}
&-\frac{1}{3}x_1 - \frac{2}{3}M(1-\delta) \le  x_2 \le \frac{1}{3} x_1 + \frac{2}{3}M(1-\delta)\\
& \frac{1}{3}x_1 - \frac{2}{3}M\delta \le  x_2 \le -\frac{1}{3} x_1 + \frac{2}{3}M\delta\\
& x_1 \in [-M,M] \\ 
& x_2 \in [-\frac{1}{3}M,\frac{1}{3}M] \\ 
& \delta \in \{0,1\}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I can't say I've verified your specific derivations, but you are wholly correct on the approach.